# Does a Charr take her partner's last name when she marries?

Tags: guild-wars-2

My wife and I are thinking of creating married Charrs, and we think it'd be cool if they shared a last name. However, we're also trying to stick to Guild Wars 2 naming conventions. Is there anything in the game's lore that deals with this subject? Is there any precedent for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what the [Wiki](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Charr#Names) has to say on the subject of Charr surnames:

> Charr surnames consist of two words put together, one of which (either
>   suffix or prefix) denoting the warband of the individual (e.g.,
>   Rytlock *Brimstone* is of the Stone warband and Scylla *Rustcloud* of the
>   Rust warband). Charr individuals generally get to pick variations of
>   their surnames within the forming of their first warband which express
>   their personality, ideals or history, though some limitations may
>   apply.
>
> Members of the same warband can also have their warband name in
>   different order than other members of their warband, though this is
>   rare – some examples include Lightbringer *Swordshatter* and Legionnaire
>   *Bloodsword* of the Sword warband, and Vitus Silverpick of the Pick
>   warband (where all other warband members have Pick as the prefix of
>   their surnames).

And here is a bit about families:

> Charr on occasion mate for life, but most relationships are more
>   casual than that. Families are recognized but adult charr have very
>   little contact with their parents or offspring, but sometimes keep
>   tabs on each other for events which could reflect back on the family’s
>   reputation. As soon a cub is weaned, around being a year old, they
>   enter a fahrar of one of their parents' legion.

No mention is made of Charr changing their names in that context; warband allegiance seems to be the deciding factor. Even in that case, surnames will not be the same for all members of the warband.

Comment: What about Gladiums? Would a Gladium change their name if they joined a new warband, or after their warband was disbanded?

Comment: I don't have any concrete information here, but as I recall, you do adopt a new surname if another warband accepts you. I don't think warbands ever get disbanded; only killed. I can't cite any canon examples of either, however, so I can be entirely wrong.